# Power set of empty set has exactly _____ subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am wondering why the answer is not "Two":

[image: Question]

Formulating the problem as per my understanding

$\rightarrow count(subsets(P(Ø)))$

$∵$ "The [power set of the empty set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set#Properties) is
the set containing only the empty set"

$\rightarrow count(subsets(\{Ø\}))$

$∵$ "[... $|S| = n$] the [number of all the subsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Properties) of $S$ is
$|P(S)| = 2^n$"

$\rightarrow 2^1$    
($n=1$, not zero, because the set $\{Ø\}$ contains a single element, namely, $Ø$)

Basic [exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation)

$\rightarrow 2$

$\rightarrow$ **"Two"**

$2^{2^0}$ would have been a much concise mode of conveying the method I used to obtain the answer above, but I considered emphasizing the steps in that procedure as it may increase the chances of finding a mistake, if it exists — a quick googling revealed many answer keys pointing to the answer "One":

[image: Answer Keys]

<sub>I have cited all these sources (inside Markdown) so as to satisfy the relevant licensing obligations to the best of my knowledge.</sub>

##### One of such explanations particularly caught my attention:

[image: Confusion]

Upon scrutinizing that justification, I am not sure whether or not to conclude that the author has misinterpreted "has" as in "comprise" because if the objective was explicitly not to find the number of subsets of the resultant powerset as a *characteristic possession* but to obtain the count of sets *comprising* the powerset, then the question might have been something appropriately phrased like (in increasing order of precision based on my limited interpretation of the intended question):

- Powerset of an empty set has exactly _____ set(s)
- How many subsets does the powerset of an empty set contain?
- How many sets does the powerset of an empty set contain?

[image: meaning of "has"]

<sub>Source: Google Dictionary</sub>

It could perhaps be the case that I am misinterpreting or overlooking words (e.g. "exactly" hinting at proper subsets?) or missing something within the context of Set Theory since I am not more formally qualified than a student pursuing these only as a complementary subject.

The intent of my post is not to assault their answer keys (also why I did not noticeably render hyperlinks to any of those sites) but to achieve a comprehensive analysis of both the answers through the Math SE community, even if either/all of it is incorrect, in which case, indicating the mistake(s) would be more helpful to arrive at the correct answer, within and/or outside the restricted options.

So, in general, how to fill in that blank technically?

Comment: I would say two subsets, but it may depend on exactly what the definition of "subset" is. I would not be surprised if a book that  has an on-line component that looks like your screenshot were using a (non-standard for mathematicians) definition that excludes the whole set. But you are almost certainly right that the intended meaning of "has" is "contains as elements".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question is badly (!terribly!) worded.

It is asking how many *elements* $P(\emptyset)$ has.  And $P(\emptyset)$ has $2^0 =1$ element.

As every element of $P(A)$ is a *subset* of $A$ then the question *thinks* it is asking.  "Consider $P(A)$; how many subsets of $A$ are there that are elements of $P(A)$".  And the answer to that is $2^{|A|}$.

But by saying "subset" is not clear whether it is asking how many subset of $A$ are elements of $P(A)$ (which would be $2^{|A|}$) or whether it is asking how many subset **of $P(A)$** are there (which would *not* be elements of $P(A)$ but elements of $P(P(A))$.  If interpreted this way the answer is $2^{|P(A)|} = 2^{2^{|A|}}$.

$\emptyset$ has exactly one subset (of $\emptyset$).  It is $\emptyset$.

So $P(\emptyset) = \{\emptyset\}$.  And $P(\emptyset)$ has one element.  Its one element is a subset *of the emptyset*.  So $P(\emptyset)$ has one subset *of the emptyset* as an element.

But $P(\emptyset) = \{\emptyset\}$ has *two* subsets *of itself*.  They are $\emptyset \subset \{\emptyset\}= P(\emptyset)$; and $P(\emptyset) = \{\emptyset\}\subset \{\emptyset\} = P(\emptyset)$.

......

So to my mind *I* would think the correct answer to "The power set of the empty set has exactly ------- subsets"; I'd assume the question is asking how many subsets of *itself* exist.  And the answer to that is clearly:  $2$.

But that is not what the question intended.  The question *intended* "The power set of the empty set has exactly ------ subsets (of the empty set) as elements".  And the answer to that is $1$.

In my opinion the fault is *entirely* on the authors for writing a !terribly! worded question.

......

(Or possibly the authors of the answer key were not the people who wrote the questions.  And the authors of the answer key didn't know the answer and they *misread* the question and gave the wrong answer.)

Anyway....

if a set $A$ has $|A|$ elements then it has $2^{|A|}$ subsets.  So $P(A)$ which is, by definition, is the set of all subsets, will have $2^{|A|}$ elements.

So $\emptyset$ has $0$ elements so it has $2^0 =1$ subset.

So $P(\emptyset)$ has $1$ element so it has $2^1 = 2$ subsets.

I think you've got that (thoroughly by this point I hope) so I'll go and bury this dead horse.

Comment: I appreciate the elaboration. In addition to the supplementary part of your answer dealing with the possibilities around the management of the answer key, it might also be the case that the question was originally designed to be ambiguous in order to stimulate further exploration of the subject and attain amplified knowledge. It is possible that one could have utilized the question in that way; however, assuming a significant presence of confusion in this specific case, also reinforced by your answer, I find its position difficult to comprehend in that single-select multiple choice question.